# Java: String.matches() или Matcher и Pattern?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

В чем принципиальное отличие метода `String.matches(regex)` от использования связки классов `Pattern` и `Matcher`?

В каких случаях лучше использовать первое, а в каких — второе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matcher/Pattern имеет большую производительность т.к. оперирует скомпилированным регулярным выражением, в то время как String.matches производит перекомпиляцию постоянно. Поэтому если  вы используете поиск по одной и той же регулярке более одного раза то Matcher/Pattern даст выигрыш производительности.

Внутренняя же реализация не отличается, класс String обращается к Matcher/Pattern

```
public boolean matches(String regex) {
    return Pattern.matches(regex, this);
}

public static boolean matches(String regex, CharSequence input) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`String.matches` — это просто быстрый эквивалент цепочки `Pattern.compile(...).matcher(...).matches()`. Использование `Pattern/Matcher` напрямую позволяет:

- Задать флаги при компиляции регулярного выражения (например, `Pattern.LITERAL`).
- Переиспользовать одно регулярное выражение много раз.
- Искать не полное совпадение, а частичное (`Matcher.find()`)
- Найти захваченные группы символов (`Matcher.group()`)
- Провести эффективный поиск с заменой с помощью `Matcher.appendReplacement/appendTail`

И так далее. `String.matches()` даёт быстрый способ использовать самую популярную функцию, но вообще этих функций много.